# Trying to use color as a property with an emotion (styled) component causing errors in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, emotion

I'm currently working on a React project that uses emotion (the styled package) for the css styling and typescript (created with create-react-app). I'm relatively new to typescript and I've hit a bit of a brick wall trying to use props with the same name as an attribute available on the base element I'm trying to style.

For instance, when trying to style a div, if I build an interface that defines a color prop that is an object, I get an error when passing this interface into the styled function. I believe it's complaining because color being an object doesn't satisfy the constraint of color being a string or undefined, which is being set somewhere else (presumably within the typings of the emotion styled function?). Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do.

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled';
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

interface ColorPalette {
    blue: string;
    red: string;
}

interface BoxProps {
    color: ColorPalette;
    notColor?: ColorPalette;
}

const Box = styled('div')<BoxProps>(({ color, notColor }) => ({ // Here <BoxProps> shows the error that ColorPalette doesn't satisfy the constraint of string
    color: color.blue,
    backgroundColor: color.red,
}));

const Test: ComponentType = () => <Box color={{ red: 'red', blue: 'blue' }} />; // This doesn't actually show any errors because it recognises that the inputted object matched ColorPalette

export default Box;
```

Essentially the error I get back is: "Type 'BoxProps' does not satisfy the constraint 'Pick, HTMLDivElement>, "color">, "color">'.
  Types of property 'color' are incompatible.
    Type '{ blue: string; red: string } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type '{ blue: string; red:string }' is not assignable to type 'string'."

This is a pretty simple example, in reality I'm using the styled-system library as well, which creates a color prop that has the possibility of being an array or object ( to set different values based on breakpoints), which it then converts to being a string, but the error is the same. It has the same issue on other types of elements, like providing a width prop on an svg element.

I feel like I'm just missing something really basic, that I'm not understanding about Typescript about how I could fix this. I can set the color prop to any in the interface, but then that essentially loses the value of the typings in the first place.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? Having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

After you added some more detail, now I understand that you are working on `styled-components`. You want to add a type for you `styled.div` props.

You can do this way.

```
const Box = styled('div')<BoxProps>`
     color: ${props => props.color.blue};
     backgroundColor: ${props => props.color.red},
`;
```

Comment: Oh, god, sorry I've just realised what a terrible example that was! Sorry, no I wasn't actually trying to pass values in rather than types, man I feel stupid. Basically even if I create the interface properly (like you mentioned) with blue and red being strings, (or creating a separate ColorPalette interface like in your example) and then using that it still causes the styled function of emotion to complain that an object is not a string, and it wants color to be a string. I've updated my example to avoid confusion.

Comment: could you update the question? how is your related code look likes? maybe I can understand more.

Comment: I've updated the example in the original question, and added a couple of comments to show the bit that actually causes the error. Hopefully that explains better. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: I'm using `emotion` rather than `styled-components`, specifically the `@emotion/styled` library that gives an interface very similar to styled-components. I believe the example you give here in your answer is the the same thing I'm already doing in my example just using object syntax rather than the template literal style. Both still have <BoxProps> passed in in the same way though. The function is receiving my types, but is then causing an error because it doesn't want color to be an object, only a string. Thanks for trying to help.